# HTML element could not work in vue js file

Tags: vue.js, jsx

I am trying to add header division to my vue.js template. but i could not add html tags into the header file. please check my files

App.vue

```
    <template>
    <div class="app">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
 <Header> 
</Header>
<Sidebar />

        <!-- Content -->
        <router-view />
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import Header from './components/Header.vue'
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar.vue'
</script>
```

Header.vue

```
    <div class="page-header">
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>About us</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

above unorder list consider as a invalid elements. but div tag is valid. Please check the below error during compile

[image]

can you help me to solve this problem

Comment: template tag missed... after inserting template tag, issue fixed

Answer (score 0):

maybe miss `<template>` tag in Header.vue